# How to keep an object size the same when resizing the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have circles that increase in width on an interval and once it reaches to a scale, it disappears and starts again. But every time I fade I `resize` the screen or `zoom in and out` the circle turns to like an `oval` or an really `stretched` object. How do I keep the circle, a circle, when the screen is getting resized.

Html

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="name-div">
        <h1 id="name">Open Touch</h1>
    </div>
    <ul class="bubbles">
        <li id="firstCircle"></li>
        <li id="secondCircle"></li>
        <li id="thirdCircle"></li>
        <li id="fourthCircle"></li>
        <li id="fifthCircle"></li>
        <li id="sixthCircle"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Css

```
.bubbles {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
    transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0);
}

.bubbles li {
    position: absolute;
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 100%;
    -ms-animation: fadeAndScale 33s ease-in infinite;
    -webkit-animation: fadeAndScale 33s ease-in infinite;
    -moz-animation: fadeAndScale 33s ease-in infinite;
    -o-animation: fadeAndScale 33s ease-in infinite;
    animation: fadeAndScale 33s ease-in infinite;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
}
/* The first Circle animation------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
.bubbles li:nth-child(1) {
    width: 9%;
    height: 20%;
    top: 20%;
    left: 20%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #93a5cf 0%, #e4efe9 100%);
    animation-name: firstCircle;
}
/* Mozilla First Circle Animation */
@-moz-keyframes firstCircle {
    0% {
        z-index: 100;
        -moz-transform: scale(0);
    }
    100% {
        z-index: 0;
        -moz-transform: scale(200);
    }
}
/* Webkit First Circle Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes firstCircle {
    0% {
        z-index: 100;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    }
    100% {
        z-index: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(200);
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes firstCircle {
    0% {
        z-index: 100;
        -ms-transform: scale(0);
    }
    100% {
        z-index: 0;
        -ms-transform: scale(200);
    }
}
@-o-keyframes firstCircle {
    0% {
        z-index: 100;
        -ms-transform: scale(0);
    }
    100% {
        z-index: 0;
        -ms-transform: scale(200);
    }
}
/* End first circle animation -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */\

/* Begin Second Circle Animation ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
.bubbles li:nth-child(2) {
    width: 9%;
    height: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 40%;
    top: 40%;
    animation-name: secondAnimation;
}
/* Webkit Second Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes secondAnimation {
    0% {
        z-index: 100;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    }
    100% {
        z-index: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(200);
    }
}
/* Mozilla Second Animation */
@-moz-keyframes secondAnimation {
    0% {
        z-index: 100;
        -moz-transform: scale(0);
    }
    100% {
        z-index: 0;
        -moz-transform: scale(200);
    }
}
/* Ms Second Animation */
@-ms-keyframes secondAnimation {
    0% {
        z-index: 100;
        -ms-transform: scale(0);
    }
    100% {
        z-index: 0;
        -ms-transform: scale(200);
    }
}
@-o-keyframes secondAnimation {
    0% {
        z-index: 100;
        -ms-transform: scale(0);
    }
    100% {
        z-index: 0;
        -ms-transform: scale(200);
    }
}
/* End of Second Circle ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

/*Begin of Third Circle ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
.bubbles li:nth-child(3) {
    width: 9%;
    height: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 60%;
    top: 10%;
    animation-name: thirdAnimation;
}
/* Webkit Third Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes thirdAnimation {
    0% {
        z-index: 100;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    }
    100% {
        z-index: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(200);
    }
}
/* Mozilla Third Animation */
@-moz-keyframes thirdAnimation {
    0% {
        z-index: 100;
        -moz-transform: scale(0);
    }
    100% {
        z-index: 0;
        -moz-transform: scale(200);
    }
}
/* MS Third Animation */
@-ms-keyframes thirdAnimation {
    0% {
        z-index: 100;
        -ms-transform: scale(0);
    }
    100% {
        z-index: 0;
        -ms-transform: scale(200);
    }
}
@-o-keyframes thirdAnimation {
    0% {
        z-index: 100;
        -ms-transform: scale(0);
    }
    100% {
        z-index: 0;
        -ms-transform: scale(200);
    }
}
/* End of the Third Circle --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* Begin of Fourth Circle Animation ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
.bubbles li:nth-child(4) {
    width: 9%;
    height: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    top: 60%;
    animation-name: fourthAnimation;
}
/* Webkit Fourth Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes fourthAnimation {
    0% {
        z-index: 100;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    }
    100% {
        z-index: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(200);
    }
}
/* Mozilla Fourth Animation */
@-moz-keyframes fourthAnimation {
    0% {
        z-index: 100;
        -moz-transform: scale(0);
    }
    100% {
        z-index: 0;
        -moz-transform: scale(200);
    }
}
/* MS Fourth Animation */
@-ms-keyframes fourthAnimation {
    0% {
        z-index: 100;
        -ms-transform: scale(0);
    }
    100% {
        z-index: 0;
        -ms-transform: scale(200);
    }
}
@-o-keyframes fourthAnimation {
    0% {
        z-index: 100;
        -ms-transform: scale(0);
    }
    100% {
        z-index: 0;
        -ms-transform: scale(200);
    }
}
/* END of Fourth Animation ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

/* Start of Fifth Animation -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
.bubbles li:nth-child(5) {
    width: 9%;
    height: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 10%;
    animation-name: fifthAnimation;
}
/* Webki Fifth Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes fifthAnimation {
    0% {
        z-index: 100;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    }
    100% {
        z-index: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(200);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fifthAnimation {
    0% {
        z-index: 100;
        -moz-transform: scale(0);
    }
    100% {
        z-index: 0;
        -moz-transform: scale(200);
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes fifthAnimation {
    0% {
        z-index: 100;
        -ms-transform: scale(0);
    }
    100% {
        z-index: 0;
        -ms-transform: scale(200);
    }
}
@-o-keyframes fifthAnimation {
    0% {
        z-index: 100;
        -ms-transform: scale(0);
    }
    100% {
        z-index: 0;
        -ms-transform: scale(200);
    }
}
/* End of the Fith Circle ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* Start of the Sixth Circle ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
.bubbles li:nth-child(6) {
    width: 9%;
    height: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 80%;
    top: 60%;
    animation-name: sixthAnimation;
}
/* Webkit sixth animation */
@-webkit-keyframes sixthAnimation {
    0% {
        z-index: 100;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    }
    100% {
        z-index: 0;
        -webkit-transform: scale(200);
    }
}
/* Mozilla Sixth Animation */
@-moz-keyframes sixthAnimation {
    0% {
        z-index: 100;
        -moz-transform: scale(0);
    }
    100% {
        z-index: 0;
        -moz-transform: scale(200);
    }
}
/* MS Sixth Animation */
@-ms-keyframes sixthAnimation {
    0% {
        z-index: 100;
        -ms-transform: scale(0);
    }
    100% {
        z-index: 0;
        -ms-transform: scale(200);
    }
}
@-o-keyframes sixthAnimation {
    0% {
        z-index: 100;
        -ms-transform: scale(0);
    }
    100% {
        z-index: 0;
        -ms-transform: scale(200);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of providing `width` and `height` in `%`, use in `px`. Change following line:

```
width:100%;
height: 100%;
```

to

```
width:100px;
height: 100px;
```

and try again.

**Explanation:** When you are using `height` and `width` in `%`, then these properties are dependent on the container, ie `window` in your case, but if you provide these in `px` then it remains the same irrespective of the container height width.

Comment: Wow can I ask you two more questions?

Comment: If you think i will help you then yes, you can :)

Comment: Well one I literally just fixed with the help of this answer thank you :) and second, for my animation it works fine but when I like open another tab and stay there for like 1 min and come back, all my animations start at like the same time and I have to refresh to fix it. How can i fixed that. Code pen link ----> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Zevrda

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is what i think you can use this :

```
width:100vw;
height: 100vh;
```

Your div will get the exact size of the window